# Getting error(TestMethod do not support Web service callouts) test class is failing because of the existing trigger on Job__c which making callouts

Tags: apex, unit-test, email, batch, singleemailmessage

Not able to cover only Email messaging part in Execute method in batch class coverage is 62%

Any help will be aprreciated.

Batch class-

```
global class SendEmailJobsAlertBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
 {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query = 'select ID,Vendor__c, name,Job_Technologies__c,Email__c,Job_Countries__c,Status__c,(select id,name,Status__c,Job_Technology__c from Jobs__r) from Account where Vendor__c=true and Job_Countries__c includes (\'India\') and (Status__c=\'In_Process\' OR Status__c=\'NDA Signed\' OR Status__c=\'Empanelled\') and Email__c!=null';
        system.debug('query==>'+query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
       
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)
    {
        EmailTemplate Etemp;
        Etemp = [Select Id,Subject,name,Description,Markup,HtmlValue,DeveloperName,Body from EmailTemplate where name ='Vendoremailtemplate']; 
        system.debug('Etemp==>'+Etemp);
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        List<Job__c> Jobslist;
        datetime dt = System.now()-1;
        
        for(Account a : scope)
        {
           Jobslist =[select id,name,Status__c,Job_Technology__c from Job__c where Account__c=:a.Id and (createddate>=:dt) and Job_Technology__c!=null];       
            if(Jobslist.size()>0)
            {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();      
                message.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());     
                message.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
                message.setSaveAsActivity(True); 
                message.setTemplateID(Etemp.Id);
                message.setWhatId(a.Id);             
                message.settoAddresses(new List<String>{a.Email__c});
                message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                mailsToSend.add(message); 
            }
        }
         Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(mailsToSend);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
     }

}
```

---

@isTest
public class Test_sendjobstocontact {

```
@isTest   
Public  static  void testmethod1()
{
    
    Account testaccount=new Account();
    testaccount.name='Test Account22';
    Insert testaccount;
    
    Contact c=new contact();
    c.LastName='Test Contact';
    c.Email='abc@abc.com';
    Insert c;
    
    Job__c Job=new Job__c();
    Job.name='Test Job';
    Job.Job_Technology__c='PHP';
    Job.Status__c='Active';
    Job.Account__c=testaccount.Id;
    Job.Location__c='Pune';
    Job.Primary_contact_on_Job__c=c.id;
    Insert Job;
    
    
    Candidate__c Testcandidate=new Candidate__c();
    Testcandidate.Name='Test Candidate';
    Testcandidate.Technology__c='PHP';
    Testcandidate.RecordTypeId ='0125G000000faM0QAI';
    Testcandidate.Designation__c='Salesforce Developer';
    Testcandidate.createddate=system.today();
    Testcandidate.Job_Title__c=Job.ID;
    Testcandidate.Account__c=testaccount.id;
    Insert Testcandidate;
    
    
    test.startTest(); 
        
    sendjobstocontact  obj = new sendjobstocontact();
    obj.getcandidatedisplaylist();
    
    test.stopTest();

}
```

}

Comment: Test.isRunningTest() will always return true, because this code is in test itself.  isRunningTest method should not be used in test class, because we already know we are running tests.

Comment: I added Test.isRunningTest()  because I am getting error (Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts) from existing trigger on Job object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to address your main code, your batchable class can be optimized to just:

```
public class SendEmailJobsAlertBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            select id
            from 
            where Vendor__c=true and 
                Job_Countries__c includes ('India') and 
                Status__c IN ('In_Process','NDA Signed','Empanelled') and 
                Email__c != null and
                Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Job__c AND Createddate >= :DateTime.now()-1 AND Job_Technology__c != null)
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
        EmailTemplate Etemp = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where name ='Vendoremailtemplate'];
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(Account a : scope) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();      
            message.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());     
            message.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            message.setSaveAsActivity(True); 
            message.setTemplateID(Etemp.Id);
            message.setWhatId(a.Id);             
            message.settoAddresses(new List<String>{a.Email__c});
            message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
            mailsToSend.add(message); 
        }
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(mailsToSend);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

This will drastically reduce the amount of code you need to test.

For your actual unit test, you just need to set up a mock:

```
class JobMockCallout implements HttpCallout {
  public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setBody( /* set an expected return value here */ );
    return res;
  }
}
```

---

Don't use global if you don't need to. Interfaces are satisfied with just being public.

Don't query fields you don't intend to use.

Don't use subqueries in the start method, only query in the execute method, if necessary.

Do use the subquery filter so you don't need to process accounts that have no jobs to process.

Use the IN operator when it makes sense (instead of `FIELD EQUALS A OR FIELD EQUALS B ...`).

Do you need to use the account Email? If you can set user Ids as the target, you'll save against the daily limit of 5,000 emails to external addresses.

---

Then, in your unit test, set the mock:

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new JobMockCallout());
```

After that, you should have everything you need to make your unit test work.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much :)